# Painting points on a MapLayer using GluonHQ Maps with JavaFX does not work

Tags: java, javafx, maps, gluon, gluon-desktop

I am using GluonHQ Maps 1.0.3 in JavaFX and I have a problem painting nodes on the map.

I have a class `GridMapController` which has a `MapView` called `gridMap`.
I also have a class `GridPaintLayer` that extends the `MapLayer` and where all paintings are done. The `GridPaintLayer` is added to the `GridMapController`'s `gridMap` with the method `gridMap.addLayer(gridPaintLayer)`. This class (`GridPaintLayer`) has a method `addNode(NodeInputModel)` to which I pass a node (that contains lat/lon values) that shall be painted. The mentioned `gridMap` (`MapView`) can be right-clicked, a popup menu opens where I can choose "Create Node". This calls a method `createNodeItemClicked()` which is implemented in the `GridPaintLayer` (see below). When I click the "Create Node" menu item, everything works fine and a point appears on the map.

In another part of the programm I have an observable object that notifies its observers whenever a node is added. The notification message is handled in the `GridMapController` which then calls the `addNode()` method from the `GridPaintLayer`. But now, when I want the `GridPaintLayer's` `baseMap` to calculate the the points position on the scene, the method `baseMap.getMapPoint(double lat, double lon)` returns `null` because the baseMap's scene is `null`. So the node cannot be painted.
This happens i.e. when I want to create a node at another part of the application. The observable notifies the `GridMapController` (among others) correctly but then the problem appears as described above.

The methods below are both implemented in the `GridPaintLayer` class.

```java
public void addNode(NodeInputModel nodeInputModel) {
    Circle circle = new Circle(7, Color.RED);
    circle.setCursor(Cursor.HAND);
    circle.setVisible(true);

    paintedNodes.put(nodeInputModel, circle);

    Point2D mapPoint = baseMap.getMapPoint(nodeInputModel.getLat(), nodeInputModel.getLon());
    if(mapPoint != null) {
        circle.setTranslateX(mapPoint.getX());
        circle.setTranslateY(mapPoint.getY());
    } else {
        System.out.println("Could not calculate node position, baseMap scene = null: " + (baseMap.getScene() == null));
    }

    AtomicReference<Double> orgSceneX = new AtomicReference<>(0d);
    AtomicReference<Double> orgSceneY = new AtomicReference<>(0d);

    circle.setOnMousePressed(mousePressedEvent -> {...});

    circle.setonMouseClicked(mouseEvent -> {...});

    this.getChildren().add(circle);
    this.markDirty();
}

public void createNodeItemClicked(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
    // Convert mouseEvent position to geo position
    MapPoint mapPoint = baseMap.getMapPosition(mouseEvent.getX(), mouseEvent.getY());
    LatLon latLon = new LatLon(mapPoint.getLatitude(), mapPoint.getLongitude());
    Point geoPosition = Utils.latlonToPoint(latLon);

    // Create NodeInputModel
    NodeInputModel nodeInputModel = new NodeInputModel();
    nodeInputModel.setGeoPosition(geoPosition);
    // TODO: set the other parameters

    // Add node to Map
    addNode(nodeInputModel);

    // Send update message to GridModel
    UpdateMessage updateMessage =
                    new UpdateMessage(null, Arrays.asList(nodeInputModel), UpdateMessage.UpdateType.ADD);
    gridMapController.sendUpdateMessage(updateMessage);
}
```

I have tried several things to "reactivate" the scene but nothing worked. Is there a way to do that properly?
I hope I have explained everything clearly. If not, please feel free to ask.

Edit:
I am using multiple FXML files. The root FXML (MainView.fxml):

```
<VBox   xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.172-ea"
        xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
        fx:id="main"
        fx:controller="edu.ie3.controller.main.MainController">

    <fx:include fx:id="io" source="IoView.fxml"/>

    <fx:include fx:id="tool" source="ToolView.fxml"/>

    <HBox prefHeight="${main.height}">
        <!-- vertical button bar for grid info -->
        <ButtonBar fx:id="leftButtonBar" rotate="-90">
            <buttons>
                <Button fx:id="gridInfoButton" text="Grid Info"/>
            </buttons>
        </ButtonBar>

        <SplitPane fx:id="splitPane" prefWidth="${main.width}">
            <fx:include fx:id="gridTab" source="GridTabView.fxml"/>
        </SplitPane>

    </HBox>

    <fx:define>
        <fx:include fx:id="gridInfo" source="GridInfoView.fxml"/>
        <fx:include fx:id="gridMap" source="GridMapView.fxml"/>
        <fx:include fx:id="gridSchema" source="GridSchemaView.fxml"/>
    </fx:define>

</VBox>
```

The Splitpane which contains the GridMapView:

```
<TabPane
        xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.172-ea"
        xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
        tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE"
        fx:id="gridTabPane"
        fx:controller="edu.ie3.controller.gridTab.GridTabController">

    <Tab fx:id="gridMapTab" text="Map View">
        <fx:include fx:id="gridMapLayer" source="GridMapView.fxml"/>
    </Tab>

    <Tab fx:id="gridSchemaTab" text="Schema View">
        <fx:include fx:id="gridSchema" source="GridSchemaView.fxml"/>
    </Tab>

</TabPane>
```

The GridMapView.fxml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.gluonhq.maps.MapView?>
<MapView xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.172-ea"
     xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
     fx:id="gridMap"
     fx:controller="edu.ie3.controller.gridTab.gridMap.GridMapController">
</MapView>
```

I have already tried commenting some statements out to avoid double including the GridMapView but nothing worked.

Comment: If `baseMap`'s scene is null, it means the `MapView` is not part of the scene graph, do you remove the map, and call `addNodes` without it being visible?

Comment: No, the map is not removed and is always visible. Maybe it is not "activated" or "focused" or something like that.
From a menu item I call a method to generate some predefined points. But the map is still visible.

Comment: Are you sure the scene is null? Why are you checking if `mapPoint` is null then?

Comment: Checking if the `mapPoint` is null was only for debugging purposes.
I found out that the method `baseMap.getMapPoint({...})` returns null, if the scene is null. The debugger confirmed me that the scene is null at this point.

Comment: Yes, that happens [here](https://github.com/gluonhq/maps/blob/master/src/main/java/com/gluonhq/impl/maps/BaseMap.java#L287). Can you add a listener to the `baseMap.sceneProperty()` in your layer, and see when it changes?

Comment: I added a listener to the `baseMap.sceneProperty()` like you said.
The listener registers a change from null to some value at the beginning. Another change is not registered. But the scene value from the one that is observed by the listener differs from the value that is null when I want to add a point.
The problem seems to be that during the fxml initialization phase, everything is created two times. Maybe I will try to make the controllers singleton objects. Do you have any other idea?
Thanks a lot for your help so far.

Comment: It looks like you have two instances of MapView or BaseMap, which indicates that you are doing something wrong in your controller, like initializing a field already tagged with `@FXML`... Maybe you can post your FXML file?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.
The problem was that I included the GridMapController once in the MainController and once in the GridTabController. I removed the `fx:include` from the MainController and now the GridMapController only initializes once.
Nevertheless thank you very much, José Pereda, you brought me on the right way.